# Aurelia, how to make optional binding

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Does `Aurelia` support optional binding? I can't find this information anywhere. The issue that I'm having is that I have a `title` attribute that might or might not be populated in an array of objects. I use a `repeat.for` and `title.bind` but I don't want the attribute to exist at all if this property is not part of the array of objects. Is that possible in `Aurelia`?

When using `Bootstrap-Select` with an empty `title` it throws an error. Having `Aurelia` to create attribute on the fly would resolve my issue.

The code that I have so far, looks like this

```
<select class="selectpicker" value.bind="value" options.bind="options" disabled.bind="disabled">
<option repeat.for="option of options" model.bind="option"
        data-subtext.bind="option.subtext"
        title.bind="option.title">
        ${option.name}
</option>
```

In this example, I would like to make `data-subtext` and `title` as optional attributes. Is that doable?

Since this is a Custom Element, I tried deleting the `title` property of my object `delete this.element.title` but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried with jquery but again no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test this in many cases, but I think you could also create a custom binding behavior, like this:

```
export class OptionalBindingBehavior {  
  bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {

    binding.originalupdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;
    binding.originalTargetProperty = binding.targetProperty;
    binding.updateTarget = val => { 
      if (val === undefined || val === null || val === '') {
        binding.targetProperty = null;
      } else {
        binding.targetProperty = binding.originalTargetProperty;
      }
      binding.originalupdateTarget(val);   
    }
  }

  unbind(binding, scope) {
    binding.updateTarget = binding.originalupdateTarget;
    binding.originalupdateTarget = null;    
    binding.targetProperty = binding.originalTargetProperty;
    binding.originalTargetProperty = null;
  }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
<a href.bind="message & optional">${message}</a>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a separate class if I want to use this in my custom element? Would that really remove the `href` attribute totally, if nothing is passed to it (which is what I want)?

Comment: This is usable on any attribute, if you only use it inside a specific custom element I would go with the solution Fabio Luz provided. That one will work for sure in any case :-) Or add a value changed to your custom element for the binding and remove or add the attribute

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the value changed is actually a great idea. I might give that a try. Your binding behavior is still quite interesting, I might use it elsewhere in the code. Thanks for providing it.

Comment: Be sure to test the binding behaviour thoroughly before using it. I just wondered if it could be done :-)

Comment: Considering that I have multiple attributes that might be optional, this is by far the best ways of doing it. I also like how easy it is to use once implemented. As a side note, I also have a possibility to pass a mapping structure (if user wants to use different property name(s) from his array) like `mapping.bind="{ subtext: 'company', title: 'myTitle' }` and then in my custom element I now call `title.bind="option[getMappingProperty('title')] & optional"` and it pulls the correct property (if filled since it's optional) and it's perfect. Thanks a lot, I'm quite happy with result :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom-attribute that generates a `title` attribute only if the  property exists. For example:

```
export class OptionalTitleCustomAttribute {

  static inject = [Element];

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  valueChanged(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      this.element.setAttribute('title', newValue);
    } else {
      this.element.removeAttribute('title');
    }
  }

}
```

Running example: https://gist.run/?id=f7f89f35b62acb5b4f05ffe59be1880e

Comment: That's interesting, is that the same as `@customAttribute()`? I haven't used such attributes yet so I'm not sure how to use it in code. Does it have to be a separate class, how can I use that inside my custom element class? Would you mind writing quick piece of code to demo that with a custom element. Thanks

Comment: You should use `@customAttribute` when you want to override the naming convention. For example, when you create a class named `OptionalTitleCustomAttribute`, by convention, the syntax to use your custom-attribute is `optional-title`. If you use to use `my-optional-title` instead, you would have to decorate your class with `@customAttribute('my-optional-title')`. Answering your second question, YES, you can define it in the same js file. Check my updated gist.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try after work and accept your answer when I get it working. Thanks a lot :)