# Aurelia how to add Binding Behavior in a Custom Element and within its own namespace?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am building an Aurelia Custom Element and I want to use a special Binding Behavior, however I can't seem to be able to use it (declare it) outside of my Custom Element class. Also, I was wondering if namespace exist in Aurelia for Binding Behaviors and other custom stuff?

Here's the Binding Behavior that I want to use

*optional-binding.js* - [code provided by another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673813/1212166)

```
export class OptionalBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {
    binding.originalupdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;
    binding.originalTargetProperty = binding.targetProperty;
    binding.updateTarget = val => {
      if (val === undefined || val === null || val === '') {
        binding.targetProperty = null;
      } else {
        binding.targetProperty = binding.originalTargetProperty;
      }
      binding.originalupdateTarget(val);
    };
  }

  unbind(binding, scope) {
    binding.updateTarget = binding.originalupdateTarget;
    binding.originalupdateTarget = null;
    binding.targetProperty = binding.originalTargetProperty;
    binding.originalTargetProperty = null;
  }
}
```

I tried import this way

*index.js*

```
  import {MyCustomElement} from './my-element';
  import './optional-binding.js';

  export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.globalResources('./my-element');
  }

  export {
    MyCustomElement
  };
```

and also tried to `import './optional-binding.js';` directly inside the Custom Element but in all cases, it keep saying that it can't find this binding.

I would also like to know how to make this into it's own namespace (if possible) to avoid naming collision with custom binding behaviors that might be declared globally by other code/project.

**EDIT**

I tried the suggestion of @janmvtrinidad to import the binding behavior with a `require` but I get similar result as I had before when trying to import it in the ViewModel. Also note that all my files are within the same directory, so using `./` should be sufficient. Up until now, I'm stuck in declaring the binding behavior inside the same file as the custom element, that is the only way it works so far.

inside the Custom Element View (template)

```
<template>
    <require from="./optional-binding"></require>
    ...
```

I get the error that it can't find it

```
Cannot find module './aurelia-bootstrap-select/optional-binding'
```

**Entire Code/Project**

I also released this plugin to the community some time ago, if you want to see the entire code, the plugin is available as [Aurelia-Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Aurelia-Bootstrap-Plugins/tree/master/aurelia-bootstrap-select). Currently if someone wants to use it and also has an `OptionalBindingBehavior` then name collision will happen, which is a bummer.

**NOTE**

Even after I posted a bounty, I am still waiting for the correct way of dealing with namespace to avoid name collision in Aurelia.

Comment: Hi @ghiscoding I'm looking in ViewEngine code on how aurelia works with dependecy. It seems every template has its own viewResources so it should work when you require them in your template, and it would have higher order when using resources. And also tried the same scenario you work with and it work and my case.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad I'd be happy to see a valid answer, which could help me and others. I would be glad to accept your answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code structure is generated by `Aurelia CLI` where elements, binding-behaviors, etc. is in `resources` folder. Now you can add your binding-behaviors and custom element as a [globalResources](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/5).
In your `resources/index.ts`, add your binding-behavior path inside `config.globalResources([...])`.

```
export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources([
        './value-converters/json',
        './binding-behaviors/intercept-one',
        './elements/pagination'
    ]);
}
```

Now you can use your resources globally without `require` in your html.

In terms of namespaces, Aurelia will throw an error when you try to register globally two resources with the same ClassName. You have two options when you run in this situation.

- You can use `@CustomElement` and `@CustomAttribute` decorator to override the existing convention. Default convention will assume your ClassName will be converted from `InitCaps` to `dash-case`. More information [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/2).
- Or you can explicitly `require` it in your html. It will override the globalResources then use your custom resources inside your html even the globalResource has the same ClassName with your custom binding-behavior/resource.

**EDIT**

> I would also like to know how to make this into it's own namespace (if possible) to avoid naming collision with custom binding behaviors that might be declared globally by other code/project.

Currently it is not possible. Aurelia `viewResources` is a singleton. As I believe, it is sufficient for you to add it on your html using `require` as stated in the 2nd bullet above.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but unless I misunderstood, this doesn't seem to answer my main question. I don't want to make it global, I want to make it available to the custom element only for that namespace (if namespace exist for custom element).  And I already tried globalResources before that didn't seem to work with custom element. My custom element is a plugin available to the community, hence I would prefer to avoid collision of naming, and at this point I have collision, I saw it in action

Comment: All bindingBehaviors inside viewResources which is a singleton. So the  way is to include in in your html or use `viewResources` [decorator](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/decorators.js#L268).

Comment: In terms of plugin/feature, it is not currently available as commented by Rob [here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/427#issuecomment-221284897).

Comment: So after reading this note from Rob, it basically means that there is currently no answer for my question (which is mainly about how to remove the name collision which I still have). If I want to remove the collision, I would have to use a name that will never be used anywhere else, which isn't a namespace fix but more of a unique name fix.

Comment: Just add your bindingBehaviors using require and you're good to go.

Comment: I tried adding `<require from="./optional-binding-behavior.js"></require>` in the custom element template and I always get `Cannot find module './aurelia-bootstrap-select/optional-binding-behavior.js'` even if it's in the same folder. I have problem since the beginning with custom element and import/require. I'll add what I tried to my question

Comment: You should remove . js extension in your require. you need extension if the file type is HTML or css.

Comment: I did oversee that, however I still get the same error `Cannot find module './aurelia-bootstrap-select/optional-binding-behavior'`, I remember that I tried lot of things but it never worked with the custom element, not sure why

Comment: You should check if the you are pointing at the right path, for more info can you post the structure of your app and where do you import/require from?

Comment: I made an edit to my question couple of hours ago, it has the link to my Github project/plugin, as for the structure, everything is in the same folder, so using `./` should work

Comment: If you install your plugin in another project then it should work if the file optional-binding-behavior is in dist/amd [folder](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Aurelia-Bootstrap-Plugins/tree/master/aurelia-bootstrap-select/dist/amd), but as i check there's no such file in that folder. If the error still exist you should post another question for it.

Comment: I did not push a code change (external `optional-binding.js`) since I never got it to work. So you're right to say that you don't see it in my Github project, it doesn't work, so it's not part of it.